# What are some other ways to make copies more engaging or to write in a different style?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, adobe-photoshop, typography, photoshop-effects

These designs are to be posted on Social Media pages, to promote the product and brand.

Now, there's nothing wrong in the copies. But my director (not art director) says let's try something else. Try some other styles.

We've tried 4-5 ways in a couple of months (see pics for examples), but the look doesn't change much. Also the director is not liking them. He needs something different that I couldn't do so far.

So is there something missing that we've not tried yet?

**What can be some other ways to make copies more engaging or to write in a different/creative style?**

OR to be more professional:

**How can one solve the problem of Changing the Typography to change the look and feel?**

---

***Why I'm asking this question:***

*a) I Googled to read about this problem but couldn't find satisfactory results*

*b) I believe there can be something wrong here (either fonts or colors)*

*c) I believe there are some other ways to right it, that I couldn't find after brainstorming*

---

[image]
[image]

EDIT: I haven't uploaded other styles because they were not very different. I can show you but ultimately they have same look and feel, not very different.

Comment: I wonder if your director says –try some other styles– what are you waiting for to do it? With some clients I really would like them to tell me *try some other styles*, and with others I would never allow myself to get to the situation that they have to tell me such a thing. A graphic designer should **always** astonish with its designs, however structured they may be.

Comment: I've edited details. OK. I tried but he needs something different. We both don't know what can look better. We just want to explore it. So I directly I need some guidelines or references.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because, as it's written in the Help Center → What not to ask → *is asking doing your work for free, **including brainstorming or idea gathering***

Comment: By the way I've seen many answers where such *type* of problems (not especially related to copies) were asked, and answer had been totally different because OPs asked about making the design better/different. That will also require brainstorming. So where's my question went wrong? After all I needed a possible solution.

Comment: Again using that lower left corner... which is a mistake in my opinion and possibly why it never "feels" right.

Comment: Scott after reading your answer that day, I kept that thing in mind. But then I faced another problem (I'm sorry I face a lot of problems, I don't know if it's only me). See, the logo we use is on top right. The designers before me used to do this, and I'm just following it. I tried to Google something like "Placement of logo in a design/post/social media post" but couldn't find anything worth :( The point is, if I can place the logo on top left, I can redesign the layout easily. What you say?

Comment: Honestly, it all depends on the logo itself and how it moves the eye. There are no "rules" really, but a logo in the top right is something which rarely appears in my work. I can't say if that's good or bad though `:)`

Comment: Still I want to know most common place - left, right, top, bottom etc?. Know about it?

Comment: Typically people look for a logo in the upper left, lower right, or center (bottom or top). But there's nothing stating you *must* use those positions. Lower right is generally optimal for a solitary images/pieces because it's among the last things a reader views and placing it there will help with retention.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/94050/discussion-between-vikas-kumar-and-scott).

Comment: You should really go find ads you like.. then explore and examine *why* you think you like them. That will assist in learning those techniques. It's 1:30am here.. not doing chat at the moment `:)`. Heading off in a few. And yes I stated the **lower LEFT** is a dead zone.. **lower RIGHT** is a HOT zone.. you *often* WANT content in the lower right.

Comment: Okay, thank you @Scott

Comment: @all is there some way I can edit and improve this question to remove those 2 downvotes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok... Where are the other styles?

You are showing 2 different images with the same style.

It does not matter if the director is not an art director. What needs to be addressed is if you are a designer. If you are, then try to apply different methods to design with different styles.

Separate the elements, and propose some alternatives to each element.

Image, contrast saturation, background, font size, font color, font style font position, additional elements, transparency, size, position. There are a lot of things to explore, but you are not doing it.

**Do not assume how it looks... Make and see it!**

Obviously, I am making just sloppy proposals. But I am exploring.

[image]

I am not even exploring changing some elements like the color or the image itself. The font is lousy, but the style looks different.

[image]

Probably we should explore concepts, instead of an obvious image of people watching the product.

[image]

Or instead of watching sick people using the product we need to explore the outcome.

[image]

You need a methodology, the design is not changing fonts, it about analyzing, exploring ideas, concepts and then reflecting them.

<sub>New photos by Pixabay.com</sub>

Here is a similar post. Take a look: [How do I progress my design aesthetic beyond the linear minimalist style i use for everything?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/76717/how-do-i-progress-my-design-aesthetic-beyond-the-linear-minimalist-style-i-use-f/77112#77112)

Comment: You answered my question. I'll work on it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This s a better formatted ad....

[image]

Disregarding the flipped type, if it were correct for reading, the overall retention and viewing on *this* ad would most likely **far surpass** the original flipped version.

Why....

- Lower left corner is a *dead zone* and **nothing** there will be retained or remembered by viewers in most instances. It is equivalent to "banner blindness" where users may see it but *never* really acknowledge anything in the lower left corner. Simply don't use the lower left corner for *anything* which is important.
- Unlike the original, with the photo flipped it provides the *entire* ad with an upward right motion. Upward right motions tend to promote feelings of happiness, joy. Good feelings. Upward left motions, as in the original, are somewhat middle-ground not really promoting any specific emotional response. So the original was just "there" without any emotional pull at all. (Lower left motions promote sad feelings).
- The product is in the *hot zone* of the lower *right* corner. This is the area the viewer will see *last*. Anything in this corner has a higher degree of recognition and retention. You *want* the viewer to remember what's in this corner. Place critical content in the lower right when feasible.
- The downward right motion created by the non-photographic content. The logo, then headline, then product create a "circular" sense for the eye with the photo. Reading left to right, you end at the bottom right but that photo really wants to push the eye up again.. right to the headline.... circular motions mean the ad is viewed longer, maybe for only a second or two, but that matters.

All this works for *both* the ads merely by flipping them.

[image]

And actually that left arm is a *fantastic* pull for the eye back to the child, then to the headline again.

---

It all really comes down to the psychology of eye movement. With the rise of the internet [eye tracking](https://www.fastcompany.com/90131416/eye-tracking-is-turning-design-into-a-science) has been something which has become quantifiable. But really, it's something designers have been doing forever.

Walk away from a piece... for an hour, or two.. or a day. then look at it.. and *pay attention* to how your eyes move across the piece. What's the first thing you see, then the second.. while a tad biased, you can still get a decent sense of how other may view the work.

For me, the key to creating good, effective, design for one-offs such as ad images, fliers, posters, etc., is being aware of how the eye moves across the piece and placing content where I want it to be seen and retained, or seen and forgotten, or merely ambiguously perceived.

Comment: Your answers are always really helpful :) But you know I can't mark it correct answer. But I love & respect your views and content. I wish we can meet some day :P

Comment: Well someone disagrees and down voted this for some reason.

Comment: I guess that someone also had down voted my question.